# Can't run iOS simulator from Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I just installed Xcode 5.1. Since I have several versions installed, I put it in `/Applications/Xcode51.app` and made a dynamic link `/Applications/Xcode.app -> /Applications/Xcode51.app`

I ran xcode-select, which now shows the proper path:

```
> xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode51.app/Contents/Developer
```

Which is confirmed by running:

```
> gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode51.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

I can compile osx applications without any problems, but when I try to run a simple skeleton project for iOS generated by the new project assistant, I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/IBFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IBFoundation
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode51.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold
  Reason: image not found
Command /Applications/Xcode51.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 5
```

If I run the simulator from spotlight, I get the same problem, but with `SimulatorHost.framework`.

If I do:

```
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode51.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/
open /Applications/Xcode51.app/Contents/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

Then I manage to get it to run.

How can I set this path so that the simulator can run from Xcode as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by installing Xcode from the appstore instead of using the dmg provided on developer.apple.com ...

I ran a simple iphone project in simulator first while keeping the default install directory (/Applications/Xcode.app). Then I moved it to /Applications/Xcode511.app, made a symbolic link and ran xcode-select, and the project was still building properly.

I don't know what went wrong with the .dmg. The only difference I noticed is Xcode asking to install additional components on first run, which it didn't ask when I ran it from the dmg.